# fatal error on compile command

Tags: magento2, setup-di-compile

Today i had installed Fresh magento installation., When i tried to run the compile command, i got below error.

> Fatal error: Declaration of Magento\Checkout\Helper\Data\Proxy::sendPaymentFailedEmail(Magento\Quote\Model\Quote $checkout, string $message, string $checkoutType = 'onepage') must be compatible with Magento\Checkout\Helper\Data::sendPaymentFailedEmail(Magento\Quote\Model\Quote $checkout, string $message, string $checkoutType = 'onepage'): Magento\Checkout\Helper\Data in /home/souqtime/public_html/generated/code/Magento/Checkout/Helper/Data/Proxy.php on line 7

I had tried clearing cache removing generation folder. nothing works. Please anyone help me to solve ths error. Thanks in Advance

Comment: remove generated folder and try again. also which Magento 2 version you are using?

Comment: @SaphalJha I'm using magento 2.2.6. I had tried by removing the generated folder. Still problems is there.

Comment: @AskBytes Did you find any solutions?

Comment: @Gem I had cleared  var/cache,  pub/static/adminpanel and generated folder contents.. it solved my problem